# Why is Excel rounding this calculation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

NOTE: I changed F22 to `Number` format, but it was showing the same result when in `Currency` with 2 decimal places.

EDIT: Per comments, here's the formula I used for "Regular Hours" column: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D16),ISBLANK(E16)),"",(HOUR(E16)+MINUTE(E16)/60)-(HOUR(D16)+MINUTE(D16)/60))`

Comment: Edit your question and post your formulas for *Regular Hours*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel calculates correctly. Do the reverse check and divide 97 by 15. The result is exactly the total hours. Just a freak happenstance where several decimal time values result in an integer dollar result. Change one of your time frames by a minute and see the difference.

Number format NEVER has ANY impact on calculation. EVER.

Comment: @tteylyn $15 * 6.74 = $97.05

Comment: @Arctiic `6.46666 * 15 = 96.9999`

Comment: @teylyn Sorry about that, I was on my phone earlier.  Okay, I think I understand it now, but seriously what were the odds of that coming out to a whole dollar amount?  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I know, that's really rare.

Answer (score 3):

Because the number of hours is not really 6.47 - that is the figure which is being rounded. The numbers of minutes shown should clearly total something ending in 6 (3+5+8=16), but since those decimals are also rounded, they hide the problem.

The correct amount of time is 6 hours and 28 minutes, which is 6.46666...
Multiply by 15 and you get exactly 97, because 28 is evenly divisible by 4 (to get decimal numbers, you divide minutes by 60. Then x 15 means you have x 15/60 = x 1/4).

You might avoid confusion if you keep the times in h:mm format as much as possible rather than decimals, and only convert them in the last step.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was also very elucidating, especially when trying to view everything from a tiny device screen while on the road.  I would mark both if I could!